# String not in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

So I have two strings

`a = "abc"` and `b = "ab"`

Now I am trying to find the characters in a which are not present in b

The code that I have is :

```
for element in t: 
    if element not in s: 
        print element
```

This is giving some error for large strings. I have not looked into that error yet but I was wondering that another way to do the same thing would be something similar to :

```
if a not in b:
//further code to identify the element that is not in string b
```

The piece of code above gives me `False` when I run it, I don't know how to identify the element which is not present in the second string.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Are you trying match count for count as well? i.e., `a='abcccd'` and `b='abc'` is the desired answer `ccd` or `d`?

Answer (score 4):

This is the sort of thing that a `set` is really good for:

```
>>> a = "abc"
>>> b = "abd"
>>> set(a).difference(b)
set(['c'])
```

This gives you items in `a` that aren't in `b`.  If you want the items that only appear in one or the other, you can use `symmetric_difference`:

```
>>> a = "abc"
>>> b = "abd"
>>> set(a).symmetric_difference(b)
set(['c', 'd'])
```

---

Note that your code *should* work too given proper inputs:

```
>>> for element in a:
...     if element not in b:
...         print element
... 
c
```

However, if you're dealing with large sequences, this is much less efficient and it's a bunch more code to write so I don't really recommend it.